# Split string Text separator between hyphen in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select Code From myTable
```

In a jod, I have a problem:

I have result string:

```
 Code
-----------
 ABCD_12
 EBC_11
 DEEDC_1
```

When I query data, I want to take the chain on the left "_"

And result should be:

```
     Code
   -------------
     ABCD
     EBC
     DEEDC
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can extract the part before `_` by using **`LEFT`** and **`CHARINDEX`**.

**`LEFT`** function returns the left part of a string with the specified number of characters. And **`CHARINDEX`** function returns the position of the character searched.

**Query**

```
select left([code], charindex('_', [code], 1) - 1) as [code]
from [myTable];
```

---

**Update :**

If any string doesn't have `_`, then use a `CASE` expression to check whether the string has a `_`.

**Query**

```
select left([code], 
            case when  charindex('_', [code] ) = 0 then len([code]) 
            else charindex('_', [code], 1) -1 end)
from [myTable];
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28d3f/1)**

Comment: It not work. Error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select SUBSTRING(Code, CHARINDEX('_', Code) + 1, LEN(Code))
```

Comment: It work but Result:  behind "_"
 12
 11
 1
I want left data '_'